# Why does IIS Express still work without config files?

Tags: visual-studio, configuration-files, iis-express

I've deleted the config files from IISExpress/config but Express still runs from Visual Studio. Is there another copy somewhere else?

If you're wondering why I did this its because I've been trying to edit those files and they appeared to have no effect on anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appears to be using a copy that's in .vs/config in the solution folder.

Comment: Yes, latest VS allows a solution wide config to be used, but of course you can change settings to switch to the machine wide config.